# Particle system not getting visible for first time in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am working in cocos2d-x for last two weeks.I have made one game in cocos2d-iphone. Now i am trying to make the same that from **android devices using cocos2d-x**. I am using particle system when player will collect the stars. ***When player is collecting a star for the first time, the particle system is not getting display***. After that *for every star collection it gets visible*. I have check that it is executing the function which is used for displaying particle system.

Code for adding particle system is:

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *system = CCParticleSystemQuad::create("stars.plist");
                            system->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("stern.png"));
                            system->setPosition(starSprite->getPosition().x, starSprite->getPosition().y);
system->setLife(2);
system->setLifeVar(2);
system->setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true);
this->addChild(system,2);
```

Does anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: put a break point in CCParticleSystem::update and make sure it is getting called, you may have an issue with the scheduling / descheduling of update...

Comment: I pasted the same code and it worked fine. Are you sure the same code is getting called as "jonynz" mentioned ?
Can you please mention your cocos2d-x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code once to define your particlesystem, declare "system" in h file so you can use it later in cpp file.

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *system = CCParticleSystemQuad::create("stars.plist");
                            system->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("stern.png"));
                            system->setPosition(starSprite->getPosition().x, starSprite->getPosition().y);
system->setLife(2);
system->setLifeVar(2);
system->stopSystem();
this->addChild(system,2);
```

now when u collect star just put this line

system->resetSystem();

each time you collect star the particle system will be reset and displayed :)